# Spring security filters interfering with threaded request handling?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, spring-security

The title for this question was difficult as we're having trouble even diagnosing the exact source of our issue. Allow me to begin by framing the structure of the application and then follow up with the issue we're experiencing.

**The Setup**

We have a decently large, multi-module Spring 4.x application using Spring Security. Spring security advocates the use of filters that check attributes on a request to determine if it should be rejected or handled by the request handler. We make use of these and our authentication works perfectly for single requests. However, our authentication is based on a number of data models from our internal services. To access these data models in the filter, we inject "service beans" (quotes because they're actually `@Components` but comprise our service layer) into the filter. One of our filters, the `EarlyLoadingFilter` retrieves several such models based on request parameters and then places those models in the request's attributes before continuing with the chain.

Subsequent filters in the chain retrieves these models from the request's attributes and use them to determine whether the user is authorized.

All of the "service beans" that are injected in this way are marked with the following annotations:

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "request")
```

**The Problem**

We're experiencing what appears to be some thread-safety issues when saturating our server with requests. During normal usage, it performs exactly as we expect it to. However, under load, when a high volume of requests are handled in a short period of time, we find that a given request may receive a response based on the preceding request's data. That is, it seems like request attributes are being retained between requests.

Now, I realize that servlet filters are singletons, but the only instance variables we rely on in any of our filters are the autowired beans for the services.

Are we perhaps overlooking some critical configuration of Spring or Spring  Security? Is there a way to leverage Spring's HandlerInterceptors to achieve the same result with our authentication without mucking about in servlet filters? Are we completely off the mark with thinking this is thread or filter related?

Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to offer, this issue has become infuriating!

Comment: Have you once logged the lifecycle of your request beans and ensured that the threads are not used in an "overlapping mode"? Thread1, create, destroy - with only other threads in between? You could also create a filter to execute first or extend the dispatcherserlvet itself to log request attributes as the first thing of the processing to see if there is some leakage.